# Accessing realm database across activities

Tags: android, realm

I have 3 different activities. 1 extends Application and realm is configured in this activity. 2. Data is added to Realm from 2nd activity . 3. Data is to be displayed in the 3rd activity. I am unable to do the 3rd part. I am unable to get an instance of Realm in the 3rd activity. The following is Application(1st activity that I mentioned)

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
    }
```

the following is the code for adding data to realm which is in a fragment inside 2nd activity(PurchaseDetailsActivity).

```
private void addDataToRealm(DBPurchase model) {
        mRealm.beginTransaction();
        DBPurchase dbPurchaseModel = new DBPurchase();
        dbPurchaseModel.setId(id);
        dbPurchaseModel.setAmountPayed(model.getAmountPayed());
        dbPurchaseModel.setCredit(model.getCredit());
        mRealm.insertOrUpdate(dbPurchaseModel); 
        mRealm.commitTransaction();
        id++;
```

the last one is the fragment which is inside 3rd Activity.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_purchase_items, container, false);
        purchaseTotalListAdapter = new PurchaseTotalListAdapter(getContext(), mDBPurchaseArrayList, PurchasesTotalListFragment.this);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(purchaseTotalListAdapter);
        Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: you are ignoring the return value of `Realm.getDefaultInstance();` what are you trying to do?

Comment: I solved this issue. by adding 
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<DBPurchase> results = realm.where(DBPurchase.class).findAll();

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks for the response.

Comment: You won't be closing the Realm though, I recommend reading about managing the lifecycle of Realm instances in the official docs.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce ok. thanks. wil do that